# I the password I need to access my game on StackOverflow, how do I retrieve it?

Tags: passwords

I can log in to Stack Overflow automatically because it remembers my old password through facebook I think but that is the same password I need to access my old email where my entire game is lost in time. I can get a confirmation email and change the password to something new but this doesn't help. Is there any way someone, an admin or anyone, here could help me to find a way to view my current password? I spent years on that game, and my hard drives got stolen, and now this.
Thanks so much..

Comment: this is not a programming question at all, thus off topic. Anyway, the passwords are not (I hope so) stored in clear, no one should be able to tell your password in SO or in Facebook, even boss admins. But if you go in your browser options and search for the recorded passwords, you can find it and view it, if the password is actually remembered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related